# setAnimationStyle is not working on Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, animation, popup

I wrote a code that uses setAnimationStyle in a popup window, when i check the code on a Galaxy 1 device running Android 2.2 OS everything worked great. But when i try it on the Galaxy 2 device running Android 2.3.5 OS the animation doen't work any more.

here is the code . 
Thanks.

this is animation definition in style.xml

```
<style name="AnimationPopup" parent="android:Animation">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_menu</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fadeout</item>
</style>
```

this is the animation located at res/anim

```
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromYDelta="100%"
      android:toYDelta="0"
     android:duration="300" 
    />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

this is the code i use in the activity :

```
_menu = new PopupWindow(googlePopupInflator);
_menu.setOutsideTouchable(true);
_menu.setAnimationStyle(R.style.AnimationPopup);
_menu.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem on moving to 2.3.4
Made a workaround: Animate the controls inside the PopupWindow.
My PopupWindow contained a main linear layou and inside it child linera layouts.
I tried to animate the main linear layout - didn't succeed.
Then I tried animating the child layouts and succeeded. Applied to each one of them a translate animation (a different instance of the animation to each one) and I animated them right after showing the PopupWindow. They all slide in them same time - net effect - as if the PopupWindow was animated by itself.